# MPI Distributed reading over a non-standard type

Tags: c, struct, mpi, mpi-io

I am trying to read a binary file containing a sequence of char and double. (For example 0 0.125 1 1.4 0 2.3 1 4.5, but written in a binary file). I created a simple struct input, and also an MPI Datatype I will call mpi_input corresponding to this struct.

```
typedef struct { char type; double value } input;
```

I would like to read my file in parallel (ie here using different processors) using `MPI_File_read_at_all`. I would like to use the datatype mpi_input in this function.

The problem is, I think that this function needs a buffer it will write into until the end. I tried using an `input *buffer`, but this creates issues due to data structure alignement. Have you any ideas on how to do this ?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    typedef struct
    {
        double val;
        char type;
    } input;

    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    assert(size == 4);

    MPI_File in;
    MPI_Offset filesize;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[1], MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &in);
    MPI_File_get_size(in, &filesize);

    int mysize = filesize/size;
    int globalstart = rank * mysize;

    input *chunk = malloc(sizeof(input)*2);

    int n = 128;
    int m = 256;

    int blocks[2] = {1,1};
    MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_BYTE, MPI_DOUBLE};
    MPI_Aint displacements[2];
    MPI_Datatype cell_type;
    MPI_Aint charex, doublex;
    displacements[0] = offsetof(input, type);
    displacements[1] = offsetof(input, val);
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blocks, displacements, types, &cell_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&cell_type);

    MPI_File_read_at_all(in, globalstart, chunk, mysize, cell_type, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    if(rank == 0)
        printf("0 - Got %d %f\n", chunk->val, chunk->type);
    if(rank == 4)
        printf("Got %d %f\n", chunk->val, chunk->type);

    MPI_File_close(&in);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

And here is a code to generate a simple binary file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char* filename = "test.dump";
    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");

    char bla = 8;
    for(double i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&bla, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        bla--;
        fwrite(&i, sizeof(double), 1, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are providing `MPI_File_read_at_all` the wrong arguments. In MPI, arguments that relate to the data to be send/received/read/written are almost always given as a triplet of the following form: `buffer, #elements, datatype`.

In your case, `#elements` equals `mysize`, which is in bytes and not in number of elements of datatype `cell_type`. As a result, the function reads more elements than can fit inside the buffer and thus corrupts the heap.

What you should do instead, is to divide `mysize` by the size of the datatype (and that's **not** `sizeof(input)`!):

```
int cell_type_size;
MPI_Type_size(cell_type, &cell_type_size);

...

MPI_File_read_at_all(in, globalstart,
    chunk, mysize / cell_type_size, cell_type, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//         data specification triplet
```

Also, your second `printf` statement will never execute since `rank` varies from `0` to `3` in the case of 4 MPI processes.